# How to make a macro run from a form control when the form control is on a different sheet than the data

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Sheet 1 and I have another sheet where I am putting a form control to run a macro on the data in sheet one. The code is on sheet 1. The below code works when I'm in sheet 1 and run the macro but when I assign the macro to a button in a different sheet and then press that button I get error 400. I have a feeling the solution is pretty simple but I'm stuck.

```
Sub Delim()

Columns("F:I").Select
Selection.Replace What:="InvalidAnswer;", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=";InvalidAnswer", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="InvalidAnswer", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True
End Sub
```

Comment: Put the code in a regular Module. Since you are not using any of the `Worksheet` events, there's no point having it in a Worksheet module.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new *standard module* to your project, move the macro there.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Delim()
    With Sheet1.Columns("F:I")
        .Replace ...
        .Replace ...
        .Replace ...
    End With
    With Sheet1.Columns("F:F")
        .TextToColumns ...
    End With
End Sub
```

Now you can *assign* the `Delim` macro (probably needs a more descriptive name) to any `Shape` object, including any *form control* (right-click the control, select "assign macro..."). Note:

- Unqualified in the code-behind of `Sheet1`, `Columns` is implicitly `Me.Columns`; unquailfied in a standard module, `Columns` is implicitly `ActiveSheet.Columns` and you need to explicitly qualify it with a `Worksheet` object; `Sheet1` (the default code name for the first `Worksheet` module in your VBA project - you can change it in the *Properties* toolwindow (F4) by setting its `(Name)` property) should work.
- No need to `Select` or `Activate` anything when the code uses explicit object qualifiers.